# Delete Swap Partition on Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, swap, boot-partition

i've been using dual booted ubuntu 18.04 and windows 10 for awhile now, and i just realized that swap partition can cause damage to my SSD. i alocated 16 GB of swap when i installed ubuntu, i had 8 GB of ram but back then i thought i will add double the amount of ram just to be safe. now i've realized my mistake and i wanted to fix it. can anyone tell me how to **safely** remove the swap partition from my disk ?
this is my specs
ASUS S430FN
EFI
8GB RAM
intel i7 8565U
512 SSD

installation partition:
20 gb root
16 gb swap
64 gb home

Answer (score -1):

There is a similar question on the unix exchange, let's check the most detailed answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/224348/375560

Hope it will help.

Comment: There should be no only link answers on this site. Please provide the essential information also here.